# accessing class's variable from another class without making first class static

Tags: c++, static

```
class A{
    static queue x;
    void operateOnQueue()
    {
        x.push(something);
    }
} 

class B{
    void getOtherClassQueueSize()
    {
        A *a= new A();
        cout<<a->x.size()<<endl; \\ size of queue is 1
        // OR alternatively
        cout<<A::x.size()<<endl;
        delete(a);
    }
}
```

How can I access the same queue of Class A in class B in getOtherClassQueueSize() without making it static? Without making it static I will get size = 0. Is there any workaround?

These functions are running in threads to maintain the parallelness. Another way would be to pass in function arguments but I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: Your `class A` isn't static but the member `x` is. You have the answer in the question.

Comment: Could you please post *code*. The keyword `Class` does not exist.

Comment: What do you mean with `\\ size is 1` ? BTW: this isn't valid C++ syntax. Where comes this `something` from?

Comment: if static is not an option and you have to access the queue through A instances, initialising the obj's of class A with a reference or a pointer to a single instance of the queue could be a possibility. You could also try to fill a map where the key somehow derives from the type and the single instance per type is the value.

Comment: @wonkorealtime can you direct me to some example code?

Comment: @Wolf sorry it is sort-of psuedo code.

Comment: @user1109443 `\\ size of queue is 1` this doesn't make it any clearer (and the valid C++-syntax for a line comment is still `//`). **Why** is (or should be?) the queue size 1??

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. *Can I query a person's name without a person?* Huh? What could that *possibly* mean? If I say "Alex", would it satisfy your query?

Answer (score 0):

how about just not making x  static ?
then if its public you can directly access it through a pointer like:

```
//assume 'a' points to an object who's stack has already been filled somewhere else, then:
cout << a->x.size(); //prints the size of member 'x' of 'a'
```

or you can make it private and expose a getter/setter or other modifiers

Answer (score 0):

if static is not an option and you have to access the queue through A instances, initialising the obj's of class A with a reference or a pointer to a single instance of the queue could be a possibility. You could also try to fill a map where the key somehow derives from the type and the single instance per type is the value.

The two examples including your original are shown here: [online example](http://codepad.org/sdMd6izc)

In short:

initialising the obj's of class A with a reference or a pointer to a single instance of the queue:

```
std::deque<int> global_x;
struct Anew{
   std::deque<int>& x;
   Anew() : x(global_x) {}
};
```

fill a map where the key somehow derives from the type and the single instance per type is the value:

```
std::map<int, std::deque<int> > mapxs;
struct Anew2{
   enum { type_as_int_so_no_rtti_is_needed = 1 };
   std::deque<int>& x;
   Anew2() : x(mapxs[type_as_int_so_no_rtti_is_needed]) {}
};
```